# How to set file limit for FileUpload in Java

Tags: java, file-upload, primefaces, limit

I am using Primefaces' FileUpload. Can't figure out how to set FileLimit property from Java. There are no setFileLimit function, but in xhtml this property is accessible ([Primefaces Upload Example](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/fileUploadMultiple.jsf))

```
FileUpload filenameCreateInput = (FileUpload)
   application.createComponent(FileUpload.COMPONENT_TYPE);
...
//filenameCreateInput.setFileLimit(3);
```

Comment: Which version of Primefaces are you using?

Answer (score 0):

In my application I bind those limitations with the properties of a back-end bean, but I'm not sure if there is other way to do it.

```
<p:fileUpload fileUploadListener="#{bean.handleFileUpload}" mode="advanced" dragDropSupport="false"  
                  multiple="true" update="messages" sizeLimit="#{bean.sizeLimit}" fileLimit="#{bean.fileLimit}" />
```

In your java bean:

```
private final Integer sizeLimit = 100000;
private final Integer fileLimit = 3;

... and their getters
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but the problem is I have to create fileUpload from Java bean, not from xhtml...

Answer (score 0):

The [show case](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/home.jsf) is based on version 4.0 of Primefaces.
According to the Primefaces documentation for version 3.4 there is no `setFileLimit` method for [FileUpload](http://www.primefaces.org/docs/api/3.4/org/primefaces/component/fileupload/FileUpload.html). It does not exist in the [tag documentation](http://www.primefaces.org/docs/vdl/3.4/primefaces-p/fileUpload.html) as well.
It looks like it is available since version 4.0 of the [API](http://www.primefaces.org/docs/api/4.0/org/primefaces/component/fileupload/FileUpload.html#setFileLimit%28int%29).